# Почему tcp-сервер не получает внешний ip-адрес?

Tags: tcp-ip, сервер, c++

Пытаюсь написать tcp-сервер. На внутреннем 127.0.0.1 все нормально получается. Теперь хочу пробовать через интернет и для начала хочу вывести свой внешний ip, но все попытки показывают 0.0.0.0.

Подключение через локальную сеть в интернет по VPN, т.е. 2 ip внутренний и внешний. Я хочу вывести внешний с которым смогу соединиться из интернета с др. клиента. Интересуюсь конкретным участком кода `addrserv.sin_addr.s_addr =` ?

```
#include "conio.h"
#include "cstring"
#include "iostream"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string"
#include "windows.h"
#include "winsock.h"

#define SERVERPORT 3579

int main()
{
    WSADATA ws;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in addrserv;

    char text[32];

    if (FAILED(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &ws))) {
        printf("Error: %dn", WSAGetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    if (INVALID_SOCKET == (s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))) {
        //сообщение с номером ошибки
        printf("Error: %dn", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    addrserv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    addrserv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);          //так не работает
    //addrserv.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;  - так не работает
    //addrserv.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ("127.0.0.1"); - так нормально
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    addrserv.sin_port = htons(SERVERPORT);

    if (SOCKET_ERROR ==::bind(s, (sockaddr *) & addrserv, sizeof(addrserv))) {
        printf("Error: %dn", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    int addrlen = sizeof(addrserv);
    ZeroMemory(&addrserv, sizeof(addrserv));
    if (SOCKET_ERROR == getsockname(s, (sockaddr *) & addrserv, &addrlen)) {
        printf("Error: %dn", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    string str = inet_ntoa((in_addr) addrserv.sin_addr);
    cout << str << "n";
    int len = str.length();
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        text[i] = str[i];
        printf("%sn", text);
    }
    printf("%snn", text);

    closesocket(s);

    WSACleanup();

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что мешает слушать на 0.0.0.0, в чем заключается «не работает»?

Всякие попытки автоматического определения всяких «внешних» адресов — костыли и предположения. У кого-то доступ через NAT и, скажем, 10.0.0.0/8, у кого-то несколько адресов от различных провайдеров.

Обычно слушают или на 0.0.0.0 или в настройках дают пользователю возможность самому указать адрес и/или интерфейс.

Comment: не работает, значит не выводит мне мой нынешний ip для интернета

Comment: @Lekksa, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: @Lekksa, Вам видимо надо просто переформулировать вопрос во что-то вроде:

    Как определить какой из IP интерфейсов связан с интернетом?

Comment: @Dex, сервер и клиент действительно скрыты за локальным адресом от внешнего мира, поэтому у моей задачи совсем нет решения? Что нужно использовать прокси, чтобы оба знали ip и подключались к друг другу и передавали информацию через него.

Answer (score 2):

[@Lekksa](/users/8974/lekksa), все правильно.

Вы делаете `bind()` на `INADRR_ANY`, т.е. говорите системе, что хотите принимать сообщения с **любого интерфейса**.

Именно это значение Вы и получаете в результате вызова `getsockname ()`.

Comment: Да, все верно, я хочу сказать системе, что принимать сообщения с любого интерфейса. Чтобы, если ip адрес сменится, мне не нужно было его снова указывать. Я указываю лишь порт, программа при загрузке должна сама определить какой у меня ip подключения к интернету, я его вывожу себе в inet_ntoa и дальше я знаю к какому ip мне нужно коннектится клиентом. Крис Касперски - Самоучитель игры на Winsock и winsock для новичков информация оттуда, что при указании INADRR_ANY автоматически будет заносится мой нынешний ip в addrserv.sin_addr.s_addr и мне указывать не нужно.

Comment: @Lekksa, очень не уверен в этом, у вас:

1. Два интерфейса, а соответственно информацию о них занести в один `addrserv.sin_addr.s_addr` невозможно, скорее всего имело ввиду логически.
2. Даже был бы у вас один интерфейс, скорее всего все равно все бы осталось как есть.

Т.е. @avp прав, если в системе несколько адресов, то по `INADDR_ANY` "сервер" слушает все (т.е. 0.0.0.0), а не один конкретный. 

Чтобы решить вашу проблему, могу посоветовать выбрать все интерфейсы и при загрузке вашего "сервера" выбирать на какой интерфейс вешать или выводить информацию просто об интерфейсах и их айпишках.

Comment: @Lekksa, не знаю, что именно имел в виду *ака мыщъх* (он же Крис Касперски), но INADDR_ANY в **bind()** говорит, что надо **принимать входящие соединения с ЛЮБОГО интерфейса в системе**. 

Из Вашего изложения мне кажется, что он говорил про сокет в `connect()` и что **для него** не требуется задавать свой IP.

`getsockname()` для сокета, возвращаемого `accept()` будет содержать определенный (свой) IP (интерфейс). `getpeername()` для этого же сокета вернет (тот же адрес вернется и в `accept()`) IP адрес соединившейся с Вашим сервером программы.

--

@Dex, если задать конкретный - будет  IP.

Comment: @avp, если задать - будет. Тем не менее если в системе только один интерфейс и задать `INADDR_ANY` то ситуация вряд ли изменится при вызове `getsockname ()`, вот что я имел ввиду.

Comment: @Dex, точно, с INADDR_ANY я тоже так думаю. Проверять, откровенно, не хочется.

Comment: @Dex
В один addrserv.sin_addr.s_addr ни в коем случае не имелось ввиду занести два.
Да Вы действительно поняли верно, а мой вопрос был не совсем корректен в части с любого интерфейса. Локальная сеть не интересует, конечно же интернет.

Comment: getsockname()
getpeername()
Возвращают 0.0.0.0
не пойму куда в результате INADDR_ANY сервер заносит выбранный ip

@avp, получить ip нужно не тех кто подсоединяется, а свой.
Подключаюсь к интернет, запускаю сервер он переходит в режим ожидания подключений listen. В этот момент все клиенты выключены. Нужно вывести на экран свой ip в интернете (минипорт WAN PPTP) подскажите может в c++ есть функция которая содержит этот ip и без создания сокета. Гугл подходящей информации не дал, возможно не правильно формулирую вопрос.

Comment: @Lekksa, очевидно я плохо объяснил. 

В Вашем случае (bind(serv_sock,...) с INADDR_ANY) у сокета **НЕТ IP**. Он *не определен*, потенциально он может стать *любым* из всех IP, приписанных к интерфейсам компьютера.

Реальный IP будет у сокета (connection), который возвращается вызовом 

    connection = accept(serv_sock,...);

Если интересно, то в **UPD** ответа могу положить код (для линукса), который выбирает IP интерфейсов.

--

Хотя, скорее всего, Вы работаете с интернетом через NAT и эти адреса будут изменяться роутером (т.е. соединиться по ним  не получится).

Comment: @avp, если отбросить сокеты. Через ipconfig /all, а также в окне состояния интернета я вижу свой внешний ip, значит после подключения к интернету в какой-то переменной на компьютере он хранится. Я правильно рассуждаю, если да, то можно получить к ней доступ.

Comment: @Lekksa, он имеет ввиду, что он не уверен, в том, что у вас реальный (белый/public) IP адрес (а это требуется обычно, чтобы клиенты "видели" сервер). 

Но и суть не в этом, вы всё не хотите понять, что для программы нету разницы подключен какой-то интерфейс к интернет или нет. Это просто интерфейс. И если вы используете `INADDR_ANY` то прямым способом вам не получить свой внешний IP. Попробуйте предположить все, что не входит в следующие списки адресов, может быть вашим внешним айпи:

1. 10.0.0.0 — 10.255.255.255
2. 172.16.0.0 — 172.31.255.255
3. 192.168.0.0 — 192.168.255.255

Comment: @Lekksa, ipconfig как раз и печатает данные интерфейсов. Если у Вас статический IP (следуе из Ваших слов), то соединяйтесь на здоровье. Посмотрите на адреса интерфейсов, отбросьте local, и private (10..., 172.16..., 192.168... и какие там еще?) по любому из оставшихся можете соединиться с сокетом, которому в bind() сказали INADD_ANY и он (сокет) передан в accept().

--

К моему глубокому сожалению (ХэшКод limit), это мой последний комментарий здесь (да и Ваши, IMHO исчерпаны). 

Если что-то неясно, придется "общаться" через **UPD** в вопросе/ответе.