# Определение внешнего IP адреса?

Tags: ip, c++

Продолжение темы [почему tcp сервер не получает внешний ip адрес?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/149041/c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-tcp-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-ip-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81?answer_sort=oldest)
@avp, извините за напор, но я хочу разобраться с этой темой, наверное не могу задать правильно вопрос, т.к. ответы не совсем на ту тему которую я имею ввиду.
Я знаю, что ipconfig выдает данные интерфейсов и что 10.0.0.0 — 10.255.255.255, 172.16.0.0 — 172.31.255.255, 192.168.0.0 — 192.168.255.255 оставлены для внутренего пользования. IP у меня динамический. И IP и основной шлюз одно и тоже значение.
И сервер и клиент оба имеют динамический IP и выходят в интернет через локальную сеть.
Попробую переформулировать вопрос:
 1. **Можно ли написать на C++ программу, которая будет записывать в переменную и выводить данные о всех моих интерфейсах и их ip на экран** (то, что я вижу в ipconfig /all), возможно не применяя сокеты?
 2. Или же вопрос 1, но с использованием сокетов? Решена часть вопроса

Код C++ локальный ip:

```
#include "conio.h"  
#include "iostream"  
#include "windows.h"  
#include "winsock.h"  

int main()
{
    WSADATA ws;
    hostent *h;

    char buf[128];

    if (WSAStartup (MAKEWORD (1,1), &ws) == 0)
    {
        if (gethostname(&buf[0], 128) == 0)
        {
            printf("machine name %s \n", buf);
            h = gethostbyname(&buf[0]);
            if (h != NULL)
            {
                printf("ip local %s \n",
                inet_ntoa (*(reinterpret_cast<in_addr *>(*(h->h_addr_list)))) );
                printf("ip global ?\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("er2");
            }
        }
        WSACleanup();
        getch();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

и чтобы ещё внешний ip вывел.
 3. Может быть нужно использовать прокси, чтобы оба знали ip прокси и подключались к друг другу и передавали информацию через него?
 4. Или писать код, чтобы узнавать ip через сайты типа myip_ru?
 5. Или у моей задачи совсем нет решения?
 6. **Где храняться данные о интерфейсах выдаваемые консолью при запросе ipconfig /all?** Если можно подробно, там в ОС, в переменной, ведь если я их вижу, значит они как-то получаются и где-то хранятся.

Comment: Внешний ip изнутри получить не получится, т.к. могут быть довольно сложные схемы маршрутизации. Для компьютеров за NAT'ом необходимо пользоваться внешними сервисами. Например, в VoIP телефонии используют [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) сервера, которые по запросу возвращают внешний ip.  
В любом случае для p2p соединений кроме существования маршрута от одного клиента к другому нужно чтоб они узнали об этом маршруте, обычно это достигается с помощью отдельного выделенного сервера, который помогает установить это соединение.

Comment: 1. Можно всех обмануть и взять результаты ipconfig/all (обработав их соответствующим образом)

2. Можно воспользоваться вызовом getaddrinfo (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx) Там и пример есть.

Answer (score 1):

@Lekksa, вопросов много, а время позднее, поэтому постараюсь ответить, но частями. По возможности буду дополнять ответ.

Заранее предупреждаю, я программирую в *nix-ах.

1. Можно ли написать на C++ программу, которая будет записывать в переменную и выводить данные о всех моих интерфейсах и их ip на экран (то, что я вижу в ipconfig /all), возможно не применяя сокеты?

Вот пример (кусок из программы в линуксе)

```
// avp 2011
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include  <sys/time.h>
#include  <unistd.h>
#include  <fcntl.h>
#include  <ctype.h>
#include  <errno.h>

#include  <ifaddrs.h>

#include <sysexits.h>

#include  "wa.h"

/*
  returns список адресов  
  out      != NULL печать
  loglevel != 0    wa_log
  prionly  != 0    return NULL
  Для free вызывать freeifaddrs(Result)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212528/linux-c-get-the-ip-address-of-local-computer
*/ 
struct ifaddrs *
get_ipaddrs (FILE *out, int prionly, int loglevel)
{
  struct ifaddrs * ifres=NULL;
  struct ifaddrs * ifa=NULL;
  void * tmp=NULL;
  char   buf[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

  getifaddrs(&ifres);

  for (ifa = ifres; ifa != NULL; ifa = ifa->ifa_next) {
    if (ifa ->ifa_addr->sa_family==AF_INET) { // check it is IP4
      // is a valid IP4 Address
      tmp=&((struct sockaddr_in *)ifa->ifa_addr)->sin_addr;
      inet_ntop(AF_INET, tmp, buf, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
      if (out)
         fprintf(out,"IP4 %s IP Address %s\n", ifa->ifa_name, buf); 
      if (loglevel)
         wa_log(INFO,"IP4 %s IP Address %s\n", ifa->ifa_name, buf); 
    } else if (ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family==AF_INET6) { // check it is IP6
      // is a valid IP6 Address
      tmp=&((struct sockaddr_in6 *)ifa->ifa_addr)->sin6_addr;
      inet_ntop(AF_INET6, tmp, buf, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
      if (out)
         fprintf(out,"IP6 %s IP Address %s\n", ifa->ifa_name, buf);
      if (loglevel)
         wa_log(INFO,"IP6 %s IP Address %s\n", ifa->ifa_name, buf); 
    } 
  }
  if (prionly) {
    if (ifres!=NULL) 
      freeifaddrs(ifres);
    ifres = NULL;
  }
  return ifres;
}
```

В нем, конечно часть Вам не нужна, но думаю с печатью все ясно. Реально у меня выводит в лог

```
2012/09/30 02:51:50 [1992:1992] Start logging (pid 1992 tid 1992) at Sun, 30 Sep 2012 02:51:50 MSK
2012/09/30 02:51:50 [1992:1992] Working directory: /home/avp/src/ig/web-agent
2012/09/30 02:51:50 [1992:1992] IP4 lo IP Address 127.0.0.1
2012/09/30 02:51:50 [1992:1992] IP4 eth0 IP Address 192.168.0.102
2012/09/30 02:51:50 [1992:1992] IP6 lo IP Address ::1
2012/09/30 02:51:50 [1992:1992] IP6 eth0 IP Address fe80::a00:27ff:fe2e:5127
2012/09/30 02:51:50 [1992:1992] Start listening interface INADDR_ANY port 12380
```

Реально вам нужен аналог вызова `getifaddrs()` (см. man getifaddrs) для винды.

Ответы на остальные вопросы

1. уже
2. Сокеты не нужны
3. Один из вариантов
4. IMHO не поможет
5. Решение безусловно есть. Смотрите в сторону "динамический dns" в гугле и/или "пробрасывания портов" в роутере. Откровенно, сам никогда такими штуками не занимался. Всегда либо работал со статикой, либо сетевики обеспечивали связь.
6. Данные хранятся в ядре ОС, устанавливаются при загрузке/получении адреса по DHCP.

Почему-то номера "сползают" на 1 (и не получается с 2)

P.S. Надеюсь кто-нибудь из действительно компетентных в сетях подхватит тему.